# Adding iOS to Ionic 7 project, how to pass NPM --force argument

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm-install, capacitor, ionic-native

I would like to run "ionic capacitor add ios" and specify the NPM --force argument.
The first thing "ionic capacitor add ios" does is execute "npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/ios@4.8.0" when I execute this command.
NPM exits out with an error because of version dependences and stops.
I can run "npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/ios@4.8.0 --force" and it completes.
My question is how do I get Ionic to pass the --force to NPM?

Background
I recently updated from ionic 4 to 7. We also switched from Cordova to Capacitor 4, and Angular 15.
I just created a new project and pulled the old code in 1 component at a time. I updated the plugins as I went. It was easier than you might think.

Previously my project used rxjs version 6.5.0 but Ionic 7 requires 7.5.0 or greater.
When I run "npm install" I have several plugins that still require rxjs@6.5.0 and because of this I get lots of warning and install fails.

However, I used "npm install --force" and everything installed. And so far everything works as expected.
I was able to add android support with "ionic capacitor add android" without issues.
There were warnings, but I have tested the app and everything appears to work fine.
All the warnings are related to version dependence.

Now it is time to add iOS support. When I run "ionic capacitor add ios" I get the following errors and iOS is never added:

> npm.cmd i -E @capacitor/ios@4.8.0
> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: @ionic-native/calendar@5.36.0
> npm ERR! Found: rxjs@7.5.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
> npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/common@15.2.9
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
> npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.2.9" from @angular/forms@15.2.9
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/forms
> npm ERR!       peer @angular/forms@">=14.0.0" from @ionic/angular@7.0.6
> npm ERR!       node_modules/@ionic/angular
> npm ERR!         @ionic/angular@"^7.0.6" from the root project
> npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!     peer @angular/common@"15.2.9" from @angular/platform-browser@15.2.9
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
> npm ERR!       peer @angular/platform-browser@"15.2.9" from @angular/forms@15.2.9
> npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
> npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@">=14.0.0" from @ionic/angular@7.0.6
> npm ERR!         node_modules/@ionic/angular
> npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!       3 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, the root project)
> npm ERR!     4 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router, ...)
> npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^6.5.3 || ^7.4.0" from @angular/core@15.2.9
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/core
> npm ERR!     peer @angular/core@"15.2.9" from @angular/common@15.2.9
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/common
> npm ERR!       peer @angular/common@"15.2.9" from @angular/forms@15.2.9
> npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/forms
> npm ERR!         peer @angular/forms@">=14.0.0" from @ionic/angular@7.0.6
> npm ERR!         node_modules/@ionic/angular
> npm ERR!         1 more (the root project)
> npm ERR!       5 more (@angular/platform-browser, ...)
> npm ERR!     peerOptional @angular/core@"15.2.9" from @angular/compiler@15.2.9
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/compiler
> npm ERR!       peer @angular/compiler@"15.2.9" from @angular/compiler-cli@15.2.9
> npm ERR!       node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
> npm ERR!         peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^15.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@15.2.8
> npm ERR!         node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
> npm ERR!         2 more (@ngtools/webpack, the root project)
> npm ERR!       2 more (@angular/platform-browser-dynamic, the root project)
> npm ERR!     6 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
> npm ERR!   7 more (@angular/forms, @angular/router, ...)
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/calendar@5.36.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic-native/calendar
> npm ERR!   @ionic-native/calendar@"^5.36.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@6.6.7
> npm ERR! node_modules/rxjs
> npm ERR!   peer rxjs@"^5.5.0 || ^6.5.0" from @ionic-native/calendar@5.36.0
> npm ERR!   node_modules/@ionic-native/calendar
> npm ERR!     @ionic-native/calendar@"^5.36.0" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot pass any NPM parameters to Ionic but you can use a project-level `.npmrc` file including `force=true` or any other NPM option.

This will make NPM use these options automatically when executed under your project folder, directly or indirectly by Ionic Cli.

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/configuring-npm/npmrc